# IE9 file download prompt breaks my VBA Macro

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, outlook, internet-explorer-9

I have an Outlook macro that saves and prints hundreds of PDF files every day using IE8. We are upgrading to IE9, my testing thus far shows that the script will not function because IE9 does not allow disabling the file download prompt. I can't use sendkeys, the screen is locked on the workstations that run the script. The script must use IE to download because it accesses a CGI script at the remote end in order to validate and fetch the document. It's not a direct download. So I can't seem to escape the IE9 security.

Is there a way to get the document to open in IE, outside of Acrobat, and save the document that way? I would like a solution outside of AutoIT or any other 3rd party utility that I probably will not be able to purchase/install.

Comment: Have you considered not using a browser and using the WinHttpRequest object instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx or the later 5.1 version:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That was my thought as well.  When you say it uses a CGI script to 'validate', what is the logic being done there?  Any way to post the logic?

Answer (score 1):

You say the script "must use IE because it accesses a CGI script at the remote end".

The first thing that springs to mind is that IE is probably the wrong tool here anyway.

What you're describing is an automated process (particularly the bit about the workstation being locked), so a program with a graphic user interface like a web browser is the wrong tool for the job.

What you really need for this is a command-line HTTP download tool that you can use to write a script.

Fortunately, such a tool exists: I suggest you download [WGet](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

You can then open a command prompt and simply write:

```
wget http://servername/filename.pdf
```

This will download the file exactly as if it were being downloaded by IE, and save it to the local disk ready for you to print it, or whatever else you need to do.

Combine `wget` with a few simple scripting tools, and you'll find that you can bypass IE entirely.

I'd suggest that this is a far better solution than trying to make IE act the way you're doing.

Hope that helps.